# Why does my Keyboard not allow me to finish writing my e-mail, but work otherwise? Video Link

Tags: keyboard, mail.app, video, google-chrome

MacBook Pro (Late 2011), OS X 10.10.4.

Increasingly Mail.app (Ver. 8.2) and Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)) do not allow me to type the rest of my input.

This evening it happened and was able to take this 9 second screen capture. ([YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1Qy4hrUpQ)).

You can see that despite furious typing (shown on the Keyboard viewer) I simply cannot type the rest of my sentence.

Switching apps with alt + Tab, however, works fine.

Where do I begin to investigate this?

Still to try:

• Replicating under safe boot
• Replicating with different user
• Resetting PRAM (or whatever it is called nowadays)

Who can help?

Comment: please make your video "public" not private.

Comment: The video is private. So I can't watch but it sounds like the problem experienced. I have the problem when a specific app is open. In my case I can narrow it down to _Docear_ or _Remind Me Later_. I reset PRAM and that seemed to help. Atleast the behaviour occurs less frequently. If I do not open the apps the behaviour does not occur. I think it is some kind of window focus bug. Sadly I have not found a final solution to this behaviour.

Comment: Video still private...

Comment: Video no longer private